# phonegap cordova 3.3 plugin fail to fetch registry in android

Tags: android, git, cordova

Basically my problem is i can run the android app but i need to access the camera as well but thats where the problem starts 
. i have tried reinstalling node.js , git , cordova but to no avail

my error is as follows

```
C:\hello>cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.camera" via plugin registry
Error: Fetching plugin failed: Error: Failed to fetch package information for or
g.apache.cordova.camera
at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\plugin.js:105:
41
at _rejected (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_mo
dules\q\q.js:808:24)
at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.j
s:834:30
at Promise.when (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node
_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.j
s:574:44
at flush (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_module
s\q\q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Advance thanks for anyone who helps

Comment: Hmm, does this happen on all plugins you attempt to add?

Comment: Yes, i am using the examples from the api documentation.i cannot add any of the plugins

Comment: Strange, what happens when you do `cordova -v`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory is down: http://plugins.cordova.io/. Not sure when it will be fixed, but that's presumably the issue.

Comment: Yes, it was the server being down that was the problem. Thanks alot man.

Comment: Awesome - glad it was something simple.